# How to get rid of <class 'str'> when using print for string variable?

Tags: python, string

I'm new in Python guys and I need some help.

I have a variable - byte = str - which I combine with other integer variable, but when it's printed out, after the value of the variable I get this - . Is there any chance to get rid of this or it can be done?

I'm giving you the part of the code and the print result I'm getting.

Thank you.

```
SUM = int
byte = str

...

byte = str(byte) + str(SUM)

print ('Cout = ' + str(Cout) + ', Byte = ' + byte)
```

And when it prints the last part I get:

```
Cout = 1, Byte = <class 'str'>11010100
```

Is there any possibility to remove `<class 'str'>`?

Comment: `byte = str` doesn't do what you think it does. Python doesn't require you to declare variables or their types, and that's not setting the type of `byte`.

Comment: You don't have to declare the types of variables.  remove `SUM = int` and `byte = str`.  They aren't doing what you expect them to

Comment: Um, what are you trying to do here? You shouldn't shadow the built-in functions `int`, `byte`, or `str`. Use other names.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you're not giving us enough information to help. If this is the entirety of your code then your problem is that you're adding a class to another class. I don't think this is your intention because you have SUM being represented as "11010100".

So the question is what do you want to do with these things? If you intend on just combining two strings you can do that in this way:

```
In [1]: value1 = 10

In [2]: value2 = '10'

In [3]: value3 = str(value1) + str(value2)

In [4]: print value3
1010
```

If you want to add these two values together you would do it this way:

```
In [1]: value1 = 10

In [2]: value2 = '10'

In [3]: value3 = int(value1) + int(value2)

In [4]: print value3
20
```

If this is not your intention, then you'll need to give more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

You particular problem is `str(byte)`, where `byte = str`.  The result is `str(str)`, which is `<class 'str'>`.  To get rid of this, don't print it, and don't add it to anything else.